# Explicitly decrement the offset in Kafka (for retrying/reprocessing a Kafka message)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a Kafka queue with Auto commit set to true. I am looking for an option to set the offset to a previous position in case an error has occurred while processing the current message.  Something like:

```
var consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(client, topics, options);


consumer.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log('Got msg', message);
        var currentOffset = message.offset;

 /* 
//program logic which caused exception and we want to decrement the offset, so that the same message is picked again

*/
    if(errorOccured){
        handleErrorCondition(currentOffset);
    }


});

//this function sets the offset the current-1 position
function handleErrorCondition(currentOffset){

    offset.commit(groupId, [
        { topic: 'test-kafka', partition: 0, offset: (currentOffset-1) }
    ], function (err, data) {
        console.log('Attempted to commit the offset @ '+(currentOffset-1));
        var jsnData = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(err+' - '+jsnData);
    });
//consumer.setOffset('test-kafka', 0, (currentOffset -1));//this didnt work either
}
```

But this code doesnt set the offset to "currentOffset -1", it just keeps on reading new messages. The basic intention is to reprocess a failed message by decrementing the offset. I also did try setting "autocommit" to "false" and then explicitly committing the offset upon successful execution of the code. In this case the idea was that the message would be read again if the code execution fails(because offset wasn't incremented), but even this doesn't work.

I am using "kafka-node" package in NodeJS with Kafka_2.10(single node).

Any idea how to make it work? Or any alternate approach for solving the same problem?

**PS**: I tried an alternate approach of putting the message back in the queue, and it works, but wanted the ofset approach to work.

Comment: You're only setting this for partition 0.  How many partitions does your topic have?

Comment: Just one (partition 0). Its just a single node, single partition local env I am testing with